# What should I do with a question like: "How do I find a free proxy"?

Tags: discussion, moderation

What should I do with a question like: *How do I find a free proxy?

As you can see in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56106367/how-to-find-correct-proxy-to-use-with-php-code), the user is downloading images on a website. He uses a lot of proxies to be anonymized and to avoid to be blacklisted by the host.

What do moderators have to do with a question like this one? Only flag it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Proxies and list of proxies are off-site resources.

Requests for off-site resources are off-topic on Stack Overflow (per point 4 on [help/on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)).

This means the question is off-topic, and should be closed.

The underlying motive for the question may or may not be malicious, but this question shouldn't be answered and should be closed regardless.